# Get sub-task field information given a parent bug

Tags: jira, jql

I have a parent bug which has multiple sub-tasks. The sub-tasks have a specific field (lets call it as "Approved"). The field "Approved" has value yes or no or empty. I want to write a query in which I want to provide the parent bug id and it should return me the value of "Approved" for each of the sub-tasks of the parent bug.
Looking at JQL tricks, I see there are functions called "issue in subtasks", "issue in parent" but not sure how can I get this accomplished with any of the functions available.

Comment: Never mind found the answer. I can just use  parent in (10000) . If i have multiple parent bugs, i can use as parent in (10000,20000). Now the difficulty is that result set. The result set of the query "parent in (10000,20000) gives me 4 entries (2 subtasks from each bug). I am trying ti find a way to correlate which sub-task is for which parent id

Comment: Can you edit the post to include your comment and the updated question for the community?